# How to implement persistentcookiejar with webview

Tags: android, cookies, android-webview

I am using https://github.com/franmontiel/PersistentCookieJar
I would like to know how to integrate it with my webiew. I'm showing my current code which does not store cookies. I searched for how to use okhttp3/retrofit2 for storing cookie and I got codes for using them but none shows how to use them in my webview.

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;


    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
        webView.loadUrl(Constants.myurl);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
                System.out.println("sammy Current URL : "+ url + " " + Html.fromHtml("<br>") + " is http url ? "+ URLUtil.isHttpUrl(url));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                if(url.equals(Constants.myurl)){
                    CookieSyncManager syncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(webView.getContext());
                    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

                    String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(url);
                    System.out.println("sammy cookie: "+cookie);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getEditor(MainActivity.this);
                    editor.putString(Constants.COOKIE, cookie);
                    editor.commit();
                    syncManager.sync();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            }
        });


    }

    private SharedPreferences.Editor getEditor(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(context);
        return settings.edit();
    }

    private SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.USERINFO, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```